# Connecting a subsite to Teams app

Tags: sharepoint-online, sub-site, team-sites, microsoft-teams

Is it possible to add a subsite to Teams ?
I suppose this would add a new team (and not a channel in the parent site) but I can't find the subsite in the Teams site list...

Or maybe this is a bad idea or practice ?

Thank you !

Comment: You need to provide more details. Is Teams a Team Modern site in O365? Where is the Teams site list you mentioned? If you create a subsite in a parent site, the subsite should be displayed in Site Contents.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the response in [this post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-365-Groups/Ability-to-connect-existing-SharePoint-team-sites-to-Office-365/m-p/70899/highlight/true#M3396) I don't believe that SharePoint sites generated by Microsoft Teams will allow the addition of SubSites.